# Entity Manager is not fetching child records after adding data

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-entitymanager

I am using entity manager to persist data into the database. Data is inserting successfully, but when try to fetch the data it doesn't fetch the child data.

Incident.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Incident")
public class Incident {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "incidentID")
    private Integer incidentID;

    @Column(name = "incidentTitle")
    private String incidentTitle;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date incidentDate;

    @Column(name = "incidentContent")
    private String incidentContent;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryID")
    private Country country;

    // Getter and setters

}
```

Country.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Country")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min = 8, max = 100)
    private String name;
    // getter and setters
}
```

DAO.java

```
public Incident addIncident(Incident incident) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(incident);
            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return incident;

    }
```

When i add data into incident table, countryId added successfully but when i try to fetch the same record, countryId comes but name doesn't come.

But when i try to update same record or bounce server or redeploy the application then all data comes successfully along with name.

Couldn't understand the issue.

Can you please help me.

Comment: what is "session.persist" ? if posting a question about fetching, don't you think you ought to post the fetch code

Comment: Hi, This was em.persist(incident). Fetch code is `List<Incident> list = em.createQuery("from Incident").getResultList();`

Comment: so UPDATE YOUR QUESTION with that, not post in the COMMENTS

Comment: also your query is INVALID JPQL. JPQL starts "SELECT i FROM Incident i". The log would tell you what SQL is invoked.

Comment: Dear Neil. Query is working fine and not getting any error in the logs and getting the data. Also, i have already updated my question.